# Native resolution on iPhone X, wtih scaled mode for iPhone 5 aspect ratio iPhones

Tags: ios, iphone, iphone-x

I have an app that supports iPhone 4 & iPhone 5 layouts. For the newer iPhones it uses the scaled mode. Now, with the iPhone X, this does not work anymore. I'm working on rebuilding the app from the ground up to properly use a more flexible layout, but I'd like to update the app for my iPhone X users before I finish rewriting the app.

Is there a way to only enable the native resolution for iPhone X, so that I'm not forced to rewrite the layout code for the iPhone 6, 6+, etc.?

Comment: If you're using launch images, did you provide one for iPhone X?

Comment: If you can support the iPhone X then why can't you support the iPhone 6?  The X is just a taller 6/7/8.

Comment: Because I'm currently using fixed storyboards and the code uses fixed coordinates (which are scaled by the OS). I would copy the storyboards over from iPhone 5 and make quick changes for iPhone X. Doing so for iPhone 6 would require double the amount of work. I'm already rewriting the entire app, so I'm looking for the least time consuming solution.